# Responsive resize not working on smaller devices ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I've been trying to implement responsive resize on my website, It works great upon increasing/decreasing the screen size to 700 screen size, then the text on the right side appears hidden.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-williams-p3tl71?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=742&resolutionHeight=675)

[Video Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo8cl.gif)

Comment: this question is not related to react it's CSS problem
you need to learn about flexbox and grid CSS you can find more information over here

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp